# Accessibility traversal order ignored

Tags: android, kotlin, accessibility, talkback, android-a11y

I have created a custom navigation line menu on Android TV that consists of a `LinearLayoutCompat` with `AppCompatButton`s that each represents an entry in the menu.

The menu is built dynamically, in the code at runtime by inflating the `AppCompatButton`s and then manually insert them into the parent via `addView(...)`.

Then I set the right order for Talkback in the code:

```
// after adding the views to the parent
menuItemsViews.forEachIndexed { index, menuItemView ->
    if (index < (menuItemsViews.size - 1)) {
        menuItemView.accessibilityTraversalBefore = menuItemsViews[index + 1].id
    }
    if (index > 0) {
        menuItemView.accessibilityTraversalAfter = menuItemsViews[index -1].id
    }
}
```

Note: I made sure to call `generateViewId()` on each of these `menuItemsViews` after constructing them.

Here is an example of a menu:

|HOME| |PROFILE| |SEARCH| |SETTINGS|

However it does not work: Talkback will never respect the order and choose "Profile" instead of "Home".

To ensure I have properly defined the `accessibilityTraversalBefore|After`, I have set an `accessibilityDelegate` in the parent `LinearLayoutCompat` and overriden `onRequestSendAccessibilityEvent` to place a breakpoint => everything is correct.

---

Why does it ignore the order I have defined ?